# Backslashes removing themselves in bookmarklets

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I have some javascript code which runs fine and as expected when I paste it into the console, however, when I run it from a bookmarklet I get an error in the console, where the browser appears to have deleted the backslashes escaping a quote mark, making the code not work. Here's my code:

```js
    javascript:(
        function() {
            function keyDown(e){
                if (e.code == "KeyE")
                {
                    if (document.getElementById("bookmarksterpopup").style.visibility == "hidden") {
                        document.getElementById("bookmarksterpopup").style.visibility = "visible";
                    } 
                    else { 
                        document.getElementById("bookmarksterpopup").style.visibility = "hidden";
                    } 
                }
            }
    
            window.bookmarkster_popup_remove = function() {
                document.getElementById("bookmarksterpopup").remove();
                window.removeEventListener('keydown', keyDown, false);
            }
            window.bookmarkster_remove = function() {
                document.getElementById("bookmarkster").remove();
            }
    
    
            window.bookmarkster_popup_make = function() {
                let site = prompt("Website?");
                let width = prompt("Width?",1000); 
                let height = prompt("height?",700); 
                document.body.innerHTML+="<div id=bookmarksterpopup style='width:"+(parseInt(width)+4)+"px;height:"+(parseInt(height)+50)+"px;z-index: 100000000001;background-color:#363636;min-height:50px;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;'>\
                <a style='position:relative;top:10px;color:white;' href='#' onclick='bookmarkster_popup_remove()'>Close popup window</a>\
                <iframe style='width: "+width+"px; height: "+height+"px; z-index: 100000000000; position: relative; top: 50px; right: 0px;' src='"+site+"'>\
                </div>";
                addListeners();
                var offX;
                var offY;
    
                function addListeners(){
                    document.getElementById('bookmarksterpopup').addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
                    window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
                    window.addEventListener('keydown', keyDown, false);
                }
    
                function mouseUp()
                {
                    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', divMove, true);
                }
    
                function mouseDown(e){
                    var div = document.getElementById('bookmarksterpopup');
                    offY= e.clientY-parseInt(div.offsetTop);
                    offX= e.clientX-parseInt(div.offsetLeft);
                    window.addEventListener('mousemove', divMove, true);
                }
    
                function divMove(e){
                    var div = document.getElementById('bookmarksterpopup');
                    div.style.position = 'absolute';
                    div.style.top = (e.clientY-offY) + 'px';
                    div.style.left = (e.clientX-offX) + 'px';
                }
            }
    
            var oglink = document.querySelector("link[rel*='icon']");
            if (oglink) var ogicon = oglink.href;
            else var ogicon = "null";
            var ogtitle = document.title;
    
            var title = undefined;
            var isCloaking = false;
            var iconlink = undefined;
            var cloakingId = undefined;
    
            window.bookmarkster_cloak_set = function() {
                if (!isCloaking) {
                    isCloaking = true;
                    var iconselect = prompt("Icon? Type '1' for google docs, '2' for google drive, '3' for google classroom, or type your own link");
                    if (iconselect == "1")
                    {
                        iconlink = "https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/mediatype/icon_1_document_x16.png";
                    }
                    else if (iconselect == "2")
                    {
                        iconlink = "https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/infinite_arrow_favicon_5.ico";
                    }
                    else if (iconselect == "3")
                    {
                        iconlink = "https://edu.google.com/images/svg/gsuite-icons/classroom.svg";
                    }
                    else iconlink = iconselect
                    title = prompt("What should the title be?");
                    var cloak = function() {
                        var link = document.querySelector("link[rel*='icon']") || document.createElement('link');
                        link.type = 'image/x-icon';
                        link.rel = 'shortcut icon';
                        
                        link.href = iconlink;
                        document.title = title
                        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
    
                        if (!isCloaking) clearInterval(cloakingId);
                    }
                    cloakingId = setInterval(cloak,1000);
                }
                else {
                    title = prompt("What should the title be?");
                    var iconselect = prompt("Icon? Type '1' for google docs, '2' for google drive, '3' for google classroom, or type your own link");
                    if (iconselect == "1")
                    {
                        iconlink = "https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/mediatype/icon_1_document_x16.png";
                    }
                    else if (iconselect == "2")
                    {
                        iconlink = "https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/infinite_arrow_favicon_5.ico";
                    }
                    else if (iconselect == "3")
                    {
                        iconlink = "https://edu.google.com/images/svg/gsuite-icons/classroom.svg";
                    }
                    else iconlink = iconselect;
                }
            }
    
            window.bookmarkster_cloak_reset = function() {
                title = ogtitle;
                iconlink = ogicon;
                isCloaking = false;
            }
    
            window.bookmarkster_back = function() {
                document.getElementById("bookmarkster").innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='bookmarkster_remove()'>Remove</a>\
                <br>\
                <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='bookmarkster_popup_menu()'>Popup window</a>\
                <br>\
                <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='bookmarkster_cloak_menu()'>Change page title and icon</a>\
                <br>\
                <a href='javascript:(function () { var script = document.createElement(\"script\"); script.src=\"//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/eruda\"; document.body.appendChild(script); script.onload = function () { eruda.init() } })();'>Inspect Element</a>\
                <br>\
                <a href='javascript:(function(e,n,o,t){o=e.body,t=%22true%22==o[n],o[n]=t%3F%22false%22:%22true%22,e.designMode=t%3F%22off%22:%22on%22})(document,%22contentEditable%22)' >Edit Page content (toggleable)</a>";
            }
    
            window.bookmarkster_popup_menu = function() {
                document.getElementById("bookmarkster").innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='bookmarkster_back()'>Go Back</a>\
                <br>\
                <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='bookmarkster_popup_make()'>Make popup window</a>\
                <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='bookmarkster_popup_remove()'>Remove popup window</a>";
            }
    
            window.bookmarkster_cloak_menu = function() {
                document.getElementById("bookmarkster").innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='bookmarkster_back()'>Go Back</a>\
                <br>\
                <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='bookmarkster_cloak_set()'>Set title and icon</a>\
                <br>\
                <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='bookmarkster_cloak_reset()'>Reset title and icon</a>";
            }
    
            document.body.innerHTML += "<div id=bookmarkster style='color:white;height:200px;min-height:1px;width:250px;background-color:gray;z-index: 100000000001;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;'>\
            <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='bookmarkster_remove()'>Remove</a>\
            <br>\
            <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='bookmarkster_popup_menu()'>Popup window</a>\
            <br>\
            <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='bookmarkster_cloak_menu()'>Change page title and icon</a>\
            <br>\
            <a href='javascript:(function () { var script = document.createElement(\"script\"); script.src=\"//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/eruda\"; document.body.appendChild(script); script.onload = function () { eruda.init() } })();'>Inspect Element</a>\
            <br>\
            <! –– The error happens on the line below -- >\
            <a href='javascript:(function(e,n,o,t){o=e.body,t=\"true\"==o[n],o[n]=t?\"false\":\"true\",e.designMode=t?\"off\":\"on\"})(document,\"contentEditable\"' >Edit Page content (toggleable)</a>\
            </div>";
        }
    )();
```

And the error happens here: `<a href='javascript:(function(e,n,o,t){o=e.body,t=\"true` but the console shows this code having run: `<a href='javascript:(function(e,n,o,t){o=e.body,t="true` So for some reason it runs a different piece of code to what I put in.

Comment: you're missing a backslash at `\"false\":"true\"`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, although the error is before that.

Comment: You have to escape backslashes by using another backslash \\

Comment: I tried that as well, also, why would I not have to do that with any of the backslashes before this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed all of the syntax errors but there are still a lot of problems with this code. Hope this works for the most part! I strongly encourage you to install [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) for writing code; it helps you catch lots of errors. I also would recommend checking out [MDN (Mozilla Developer Network)](https://developer.mozilla.org) as a general reference for HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and more.

```javascript
(function () {
  function keyDown(e) {
    if (e.code == "KeyE") {
      if (
        document.getElementById("bookmarksterpopup").style.visibility ==
        "hidden"
      ) {
        document.getElementById("bookmarksterpopup").style.visibility =
          "visible";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("bookmarksterpopup").style.visibility =
          "hidden";
      }
    }
  }

  window.bookmarkster_popup_remove = function () {
    document.getElementById("bookmarksterpopup").remove();
    window.removeEventListener("keydown", keyDown, false);
  };
  window.bookmarkster_remove = function () {
    document.getElementById("bookmarkster").remove();
  };

  window.bookmarkster_popup_make = function () {
    let site = prompt("Website?");
    let width = prompt("Width?", 1000);
    let height = prompt("height?", 700);
    document.body.innerHTML += /*html*/ `
      <div 
        id=bookmarksterpopup 
        style="
          width: ${parseInt(width, 10) + 4}px;
          height: ${parseInt(height, 10) + 50}px;
          z-index: 100000000001;
          background-color: #363636;
          min-height: 50px;
          position: absolute;
          top: 0px;
          left: 0px;
        "
      >
        <a 
          style="position: relative; top: 10px; color: white;"
          href="#" 
          onclick="bookmarkster_popup_remove()"
        >
          Close popup window
        </a>
        <iframe 
          style="
            width: ${width}px;
            height: ${height}px;
            z-index: 100000000000; 
            position: relative; 
            top: 50px; 
            right: 0px;
          "
          src="${site}"
        >
      </div>`;
    addListeners();
    var offX;
    var offY;

    function addListeners() {
      document
        .getElementById("bookmarksterpopup")
        .addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown, false);
      window.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp, false);
      window.addEventListener("keydown", keyDown, false);
    }

    function mouseUp() {
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", divMove, true);
    }

    function mouseDown(e) {
      var div = document.getElementById("bookmarksterpopup");
      offY = e.clientY - parseInt(div.offsetTop);
      offX = e.clientX - parseInt(div.offsetLeft);
      window.addEventListener("mousemove", divMove, true);
    }

    function divMove(e) {
      var div = document.getElementById("bookmarksterpopup");
      div.style.position = "absolute";
      div.style.top = e.clientY - offY + "px";
      div.style.left = e.clientX - offX + "px";
    }
  };

  var oglink = document.querySelector('link[rel*="icon"]');
  if (oglink) var ogicon = oglink.href;
  else var ogicon = "null";
  var ogtitle = document.title;

  var title = undefined;
  var isCloaking = false;
  var iconlink = undefined;
  var cloakingId = undefined;

  window.bookmarkster_cloak_set = function () {
    if (!isCloaking) {
      isCloaking = true;
      var iconselect = prompt(
        'Icon? Type "1" for google docs, "2" for google drive, "3" for google classroom, or type your own link'
      );
      if (iconselect == "1") {
        iconlink =
          "https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/mediatype/icon_1_document_x16.png";
      } else if (iconselect == "2") {
        iconlink =
          "https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/infinite_arrow_favicon_5.ico";
      } else if (iconselect == "3") {
        iconlink =
          "https://edu.google.com/images/svg/gsuite-icons/classroom.svg";
      } else iconlink = iconselect;
      title = prompt("What should the title be?");
      var cloak = function () {
        var link =
          document.querySelector('link[rel*="icon"]') ||
          document.createElement("link");
        link.type = "image/x-icon";
        link.rel = "shortcut icon";

        link.href = iconlink;
        document.title = title;
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);

        if (!isCloaking) clearInterval(cloakingId);
      };
      cloakingId = setInterval(cloak, 1000);
    } else {
      title = prompt("What should the title be?");
      var iconselect = prompt(
        'Icon? Type "1" for google docs, "2" for google drive, "3" for google classroom, or type your own link'
      );
      if (iconselect == "1") {
        iconlink =
          "https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/mediatype/icon_1_document_x16.png";
      } else if (iconselect == "2") {
        iconlink =
          "https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/infinite_arrow_favicon_5.ico";
      } else if (iconselect == "3") {
        iconlink =
          "https://edu.google.com/images/svg/gsuite-icons/classroom.svg";
      } else iconlink = iconselect;
    }
  };

  window.bookmarkster_cloak_reset = function () {
    title = ogtitle;
    iconlink = ogicon;
    isCloaking = false;
  };

  window.bookmarkster_back = function () {
    document.getElementById("bookmarkster").innerHTML = /*html*/ `
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="bookmarkster_remove()">Remove</a>
      <br>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="bookmarkster_popup_menu()">Popup window</a>
      <br>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="bookmarkster_cloak_menu()">Change page title and icon</a>
      <br>
      <a 
        href="javascript:(function () { 
          var script = document.createElement('script'); 
          script.src = '//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/eruda'; 
          document.body.appendChild(script); 
          script.onload = function () { eruda.init() } 
        })();"
      >Inspect Element</a>
      <br>
      <a href='javascript:(function(e,n,o,t) {o=e.body,t="true"==o[n],o[n]=t?"false":"true",e.designMode=t?"off":"on"})(document,"contentEditable")'>
        Edit Page content (toggleable)
      </a>
    `;
  };

  window.bookmarkster_popup_menu = function () {
    document.getElementById("bookmarkster").innerHTML = /*html*/ `
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="bookmarkster_back()">Go Back</a>
      <br>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="bookmarkster_popup_make()">Make popup window</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="bookmarkster_popup_remove()">Remove popup window</a>
    `;
  };

  window.bookmarkster_cloak_menu = function () {
    document.getElementById("bookmarkster").innerHTML = /*html*/ `
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="bookmarkster_back()">Go Back</a>
      <br>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="bookmarkster_cloak_set()">Set title and icon</a>
      <br>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="bookmarkster_cloak_reset()">Reset title and icon</a>
    `;
  };

  document.body.innerHTML += /*html*/ `
    <div 
      id=bookmarkster 
      style="
        color:white;
        height:200px;
        min-height:1px;
        width:250px;
        background-color:gray
        ;z-index: 100000000001;
        position:absolute;
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
      "
    >
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="bookmarkster_remove()">Remove</a>
      <br>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="bookmarkster_popup_menu()">Popup window</a>
      <br>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="bookmarkster_cloak_menu()">Change page title and icon</a>
      <br>
      <a href='javascript:(function () { var script = document.createElement("script"); script.src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/eruda"; document.body.appendChild(script); script.onload = function () { eruda.init() } })();'>
        Inspect Element
      </a>
      <br>
      <a href='javascript:(function(e,n,o,t){o=e.body,t="true"==o[n],o[n]=t?"false":"true",e.designMode=t?"off":"on"})(document,"contentEditable"'>
        Edit Page content (toggleable)
      </a>
    </div>`;
})();
```